# Apache Spark DAGScheduler Missing Parents for Stage

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, rdd

When running my iterative program on Apache Spark I occasionally get the message:

```
INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents for Stage 4443: List(Stage 4441, Stage 4442)
```

I gather it means it needs to compute the parent `RDD` - but I am not 100% sure. I don't just get one of these, I end up with 100's if not thousands of them at a time - it completely slows down my programme and another iteration does not complete for 10-15 minutes (they usually take 4-10 seconds).

I `cache` the main `RDD` on each iteration, using `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER`. The next iteration uses this `RDD`. The lineage of the `RDD` therefore gets very large hence the need for caching. However, if I am caching (and spilling to disk) how can a parent be lost?

Answer (score 5):

I quote Imran Rashid from Cloudera:

It's normal for stages to get skipped if they are shuffle map stages, which get read multiple times.  Eg., here's a little example program I wrote earlier to demonstrate this: "d3" doesn't need to be re-shuffled since each time its read w/ the same partitioner.  So skipping stages in this way is a good thing:

```
val partitioner = new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(10)
val d3 = sc.parallelize(1 to 100).map { x => (x % 10) -> x}.partitionBy(partitioner)
(0 until 5).foreach { idx =>
val otherData = sc.parallelize(1 to (idx * 100)).map{ x => (x % 10) -> x}.partitionBy(partitioner)
println(idx + " ---> " + otherData.join(d3).count())
}
```

If you run this, f you look in the UI you'd see that all jobs except for the first one have one stage that is skipped.  You will also see this in the log:

15/06/08 10:52:37 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(Stage 12, Stage 13)

15/06/08 10:52:37 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(Stage 13)

Admittedly that is not very clear, but that is sort of indicating to you that the DAGScheduler first created stage 12 as a necessary step, and then later on changed its mind by realizing that everything it needed for stage 12 already existed, so there was nothing to do.

See the following for the email source:
http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/

Comment: Ok, thanks! But why does it slow down the programme?

Comment: My own experience with iterative programs with long lineage is that checkpointing is necessary every 10-15 iterations. The checkpoint will make that iteration take 1.5--2x as long (you are writing files to persistent storage in your SPARK_CHECKPOINT_DIR), but will speed up the next few iterations.
The other issue I have had in iterative programs is having missed an RDD to cache initially, such that the reuse of this RDD triggers a recursion in later RDDs' lineage graphs that causes the later iterations to never finish. If you have even 1 RDD somewhere in the lineage like this, it can happen.